# SQL Server CONTAINS and highlighting the matches

Tags: sql-server, full-text-search, full-text-indexing

`Contains()` with `FORMSOF()` is great for trying to capture the user's intent while searching, but is there any way to highlight the matches.

If I search for "said", it might return texts containing "says, say, spoke" etc. **Is there a way a way I can highlight the match in the results, or Is there a way to surround the match with underscores?** So I might get

```
She _says_ yes.
I _say_ my name.
We _spoke_ for hours but he didn't _say_ much.
```

I've considered an after-the-fact (client-side) regex solution that would esentially remove commmon word endings like (e|ed|es|s|ing) and then look for my results with with all those options (so bakes would become bak and then I'd search for `bak[a-z]?(s|d|es|ed|ing)` and that works okay for words like that, but there's a whole lot of cases where the past tenses don't follow that formula, like speak vs spoke and spake.

Comment: It would be ideal to do this one within the business logic or while displaying on web/view.

Comment: Well, I don't think that there's a way to retrieve the match positions so it feels like, for precise matching, I'd have to have SQL highlight the matches (if there's a way, the point of the question) because a client-side regex simply cannot catch many of the results.

Answer (score 0):

There are two SQL Server functions that can help you with this:

The Soundex function help you to compare similar words.
and the difference function helps you to evaluate the difference.